# Extracting data from javascript webpages

Tags: javascript, xml, ajax, http

I need to build a system to extract vast amounts of data from a collection of webpages. A lot of these sites (mayabe 90% or so) are powered by various different javascript systems. I am wondering what is the most efficient method to extract this data?

Since every site is different I am looking for a flexible solution, and since there are many sites I am looking for a solution that'll put as little stress on my network as possible.

Most of my programming experience is in C, C++ and Perl, but I'm happy to whatever gives the best result.

The webpages have constantly updating numbers and statistics that I wish to extract and perform some analysis on, so I need to be able to easily store them in a database.

I've done some research of my own, but I'm really coming up blank here. I'm hoping someone else can help me! :)

Comment: 'Scraping' is quite unethical. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Some statistical analysis on how odds change at bookmakers.

Comment: You can probably write some regular expression to extract the data part(s). There isn't much to it really.

Comment: @Frits there is a *lot* to it if the data comes through Javascript :)

Answer (score 0):

You will need a browser that interprets the JavaScript, and does the actual requests for you. You will then need to take a DOM snapshot of the interpreted result. It's not going  to be trivial, and it's going to be impossible in pure PHP.

I have no own experience with it, but maybe the [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) Suite can help. It's an automation suite used for software testing, but according to [this article](http://www.sparksupport.com/blog/dynamic-web-scraping-using-selenium), to some extent can also be used for scraping.

Comment: This looks very interesting, cheers! I am wondering how fast it will be? If it opens a tab every time I can't imagine scraping 30+ websites as often as possible will happen to quickly. I will definitely investigate more. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you should try PHP DOMDocument class.
For example this code will "steal" all the table tags from the url.

```
$data=array();    
$url='your.site.com';
$out=file_get_contents($url);
$dom=new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($out);
foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('table') as $table){
data[]=$table->nodeValue;
}
print_r($data);
```

You can take and manipulate all the DOM and parse all the html document. Consider calling this script asynchronously with an AJAX approach.

Comment: This won't help in the case of Javascript powered sites, which he says is his main focus.

Comment: what about stealing <script> tags?

Comment: @razorxan you still need to execute the Javascript to get meaningful results. How do you do that in pure PHP?

Comment: @razor and how would you make the Ajax request in PHP, and interpret the (JavaScript) result? You would need a full-fledged JavaScript engine for this. I can see no way to do this in PHP.

Comment: Could I run something like SpiderMonkey to execute the Javascript in this case?

Comment: @dlmalloc sure, but for that you need Spidermonkey running, and a DOM to run in. This is no task for a PHP script alone